# How do I add quotes to a CSS Variable value, to use it in ::before/::after content?

Tags: css, css-variables

I have the following code:

```css
div {
  --text: success;
}

div::before {
  content: var(--text);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This doesn't work because `--text` is inserted as-is and produces `content: success` (no quotes).

Obviously I can do `--text: 'success'`, but not always — if variable is reused between several properties, quotes would not be appropriate for some of those.

Is it possible to add the quotes in `content` itself? Something like

```
content: "'" var(--text) "'" /* doesn't work */
```

would be perfect.

Comment: So you want to convert an identifier to a string? I don't think it's possible. The only way I know of type coercion is when using [`attr()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-values-3-20160929/#funcdef-attr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE:

This is not possible without using some type of a preprocessor like SASS or LESS.

Below answers are not answering the question, I've left them in case they might be useful to someone else.

<strike>You can put the quote `"` inside a var and then put all your vars inside the content respectively.</strike>

```css
div {
  --text: 'success';
  --quo: '"';
}

div::before {
  content: var(--quo) var(--text) var(--quo);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## or

<strike>using quotes inside content directly</strike>

```css
div {
  --text: 'success';
}

div::before {
  content: '"' var(--text) '"';
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: OP is already aware that using quotes works.

Comment: Well, I still see the same problem. The question says "Obviously I can do `--text: 'success'`", and your answer is basically "use `--text: 'success'`".

Comment: Yes, I now see what you mean. I will update my answer or I might leave it in case someone else finds it useful.

Comment: If op wants this answer removed, do let me know first. Please do not down-vote, thanks!

Comment: @Devphile Thanks -- "it's not possible" is a valid answer (I'll wait a bit before approving, in case someone knows a way). The "below answers" are a bit confusing though since they don't really apply.

Comment: You are very much welcome. Let me know if there's something you want me to change / remove.